# Где взять стандартные библиотеки Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Вот допустим у меня в build.grudle написано `implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'` Я так понимаю это jar библиотека, но где мне ее файл получить? Искал в папке SDK не нашел.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как вариант можно попробовать что-то выцепить из [хранилища репозиториев](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/androidx.appcompat/appcompat?repo=google).Там вообще не только данная библиотека есть, но и остальные довольно популярные. Так же есть так называемый [Android GIT](https://android.googlesource.com/?format=HTML) где есть тоже [код данной библиотеки](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/refs/heads/androidx-appcompat-release). [Вот есть еще ссылка](https://github.com/androidx-releases/Appcompat/releases) на гитхаб